How to identify groups based on id and sign change?
My input is a dataframe with one column :
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A1-B1', 'A1-B2', 'A1-B3', 'A1-B8', 'A2-B10', 'A2-B16', 'A2-B9', 'A3-B13', 'A3-B14']})

I'm trying to create a second column that will identify the groups based on two things :

the Axx
the sign change of Bxx

Group1 : In A1: the numbers of Bxx are increasing = B1 to B8
Group2 : In A2, the numbers of Bxx are first increasing = B10 to B16
Group3 : In A2, the numbers of Bxx then decreased to B9
Group4 : In A3, the number of Bxx are increasing = B13 to B14
My expected output is this :
       ID  GROUP
0   A1-B1      1
1   A1-B2      1
2   A1-B3      1
3   A1-B8      1
4  A2-B10      2
5  A2-B16      2
6   A2-B9      3
7  A3-B13      4
8  A3-B14      4

I tried using an idea of findall and ngroup but it didn't goes well :
new_df = df['ID'].str.findall(r'\d+').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))
new_df.columns = ['Axx', 'Bxx']
new_df['GROUP'] = new_df.groupby(['Axx', 'Bxx']).ngroup()
print(new_df)

  Axx Bxx  GROUP
0   1   1      0
1   1   2      1
2   1   3      2
3   1   8      3
4   2  10      4
5   2  16      5
6   2   9      6
7   3  13      7
8   3  14      8

Do you guys have a proposition ?

First, extract the integer values of a and b. Then group by a and sign changes in b and store the ngroup() + 1:
df[["a", "b"]] = df["ID"].str.extract(r"A(\d+)-B(\d+)").astype(int)

df["GROUP"] = df.groupby([df["a"], df["b"].diff().le(0)]).ngroup() + 1

df = df.drop(columns=["a", "b"])

print(df)

Output:
      ID  GROUP
0   A1-B1      1
1   A1-B2      1
2   A1-B3      1
3   A1-B8      1
4  A2-B10      2
5  A2-B16      2
6   A2-B9      3
7  A3-B13      4
8  A3-B14      4

Alternative way without assigning columns that are dropped later:
ab = df["ID"].str.extract(r"A(\d+)-B(\d+)").astype(int)

df["GROUP"] = df.groupby([ab[0], ab[1].diff().le(0)]).ngroup() + 1

print(df)


Nice! I suppose you can use df.pipe and assign directly. E.g., df['GROUP'] = df["ID"].str.extract(r"A(?P<A>\d+)-B(?P<B>\d+)").astype(int).pipe(lambda x: x.groupby([x['A'], x['B'].diff().le(0)]).ngroup() + 1).

@ouroboros1 thanks! I did not know that using named capturing groups in regex like that would use the names in the returned dataframe.
